# Javascript converting hex value wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know how can it be possible, but when I'm executing a conversion using:

`String.fromCharCode(buffer[i])` it is converting to a strange value like this:

if i pass the value: 179 (Decimal) and when I check the Hex value generated by this code it generated the value 194 (C2 hex).

I'm a little bit confused, because I don't know why its happening.

Here is the code:

```
if ((topic != "") && (message != "")){

      var buffer = "";

      buffer = message.split(",");
      console.log("Buffer: " + buffer);
      // &#
      var msg = "";

      for (i = 0;i < buffer.length;i++){
          msg = msg + String.fromCharCode(0 + buffer[i]);
      }

      client.publish(topic, msg);

  }
```

Observation:

When I pass values < 127 it works like a charm, but with values > 127 it don't works.

If anyone manage help me to understand better how it works I'll be thankful.

Comment: how do you convert it to hex?

Comment: Show us the input `message` please, otherwise we can hardly help you.

Comment: Maybe you meant `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(buffer[i], 16))`? Notice that `0 +` does not convert a string to a number, not in hex and not in decimal either.

Comment: @Bergi this is the `message` input: `0,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,65,65,65,65,65,65,2,5,0,0,0,0,13,4,0,1,0,0`

Comment: I can remove the `0 + ` but the result is the same

Comment: What do you expect the output to be for that particular input? Is it hexadecimals or is it ASCII character equivalents

Comment: @pedro.olimpio: And what's the expected ouput `msg` for that? Notice that NUL bytes in strings are not handled well.

Comment: @trincot it is for a communication through the `MQTT` protocol, and the protocol of my hardware is based in byte-byte, and this particular input is the same in "String" that I want to send to my hardware in bytes... Its possible I'm totally wrong in this way to work with javascript, i'm not expert on this, but I need to send bytesto my hardware. I don't know if i'm clear, if i was not please tell me.

Comment: @Bergi it's a communication through MQTT protocol, i'm developing to my hardware that i communicate with them with my own protocol. So, i'm using `node.js` to command via web page as well. am I clear?

Comment: Strings in JavaScript are unicode, numbers are floats, so for driving your hardware I suspect they are not suitable types. Look into [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)

Comment: @pedro.olimpio You probably want to use an [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) then, not a `String`.

Comment: when i use Uint8Array the message sent is: `[object Uint8Array]`

Comment: I think is the `msg` parameter must be a String, So I think: If i execute a command like a `Chr(int_value)` like others languages (Delphi, Php, Java) I can do that. Do you know something like `Chr()` in Javascript?

Comment: By now it is clear this question has nothing to do with *hex*.

Comment: What happens when you do `client.publish(topic, String.fromCharCode(...message.split(',')));`?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the code of `client.publish`. It could be that it converts unicode to single-byte characters, making conversions which result in different byte values than you originally had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem using this solution:

```
if ((topic != "") && (message != "")){

      var buffer = "";

      buffer = message.split(",");
      console.log("Buffer: " + buffer);

      var sendBuffer = new Buffer(27);

      for (i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++){

          sendBuffer[i] = buffer[i];

      }

      var messageBuffer = new Buffer(sendBuffer);

      // &#

      client.publish(topic, messageBuffer);

  }
```